# How an addon listens HTTP-headers, that Firefox requests from HTML-pages?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to the Firefox `html`-page request through a proxy, and everything else that is on the page - pictures, styles, video, music, flash, etc., requested without a proxy.
I create:

the function `proxy(type,http,port,no_proxies)`:

```
var prefsvc = require("sdk/preferences/service");
function proxy(type,http,port,no_proxies) {
    prefsvc.set("network.proxy.type", type);
    prefsvc.set("network.proxy.http", http);
    prefsvc.set("network.proxy.http_port", port);
    prefsvc.set("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", no_proxies);}
```

the button:
`var button = require('sdk/ui/button/action').ActionButton({id: "proxy-button", label: "Proxy Button", icon: {"16": "./icon-16.png"}, onClick: handleClick});`

a function `handleClick(state)`, that:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
function handleClick(state) {
```

opens a new tab:
`tabs.open("https://developer.mozilla.org/");`

requests by URL of this tab `Content-Type`-header from target server and if it coincides with the heading of `html`-page (`text/html`), then change the proxy of Firefox, and if the request is not `html`-page, the proxy is disabled:

```
Request({url: tabs.activeTab.url, onComplete: function (response) {
'text/html'==response.headers['Content-Type'].split(';',1) 
? proxy(1,"192.168.56.101",8880,"localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.1")
: proxy(5,'','','');
}}).head();}
```

Now the question:
How can I listen to all the http requests that come from links on a page?
Thanks.